# iPhone 4s update from iOS 6 to iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone

I have an iPhone 4s still running on some version of iOS 6. Is it possible to upgrade to only iOS 7.1.2 without going to iOS 8? Apple stopped signing iOS 7.1.2, which makes me wonder if I can do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apple will only sign the latest version of iOS on any device that can accept the update, so your choices are stay on iOS 6 or update to iOS 8.1

There is usually a brief period of grace during which they will still sign the last iOS, but that is long over for iOS 8.